# Can a parent process change pid of his children?

Tags: unix, posix

I have a simple question.

I'm writing a program in which a parent process forks and execute multiple children.
I have the impression that when a parent process kills or create a child process the pids of the other children change.

Is that true?

Comment: Simply: no, it's not true.

Comment: No. What changes in the children is the *parent* process ID, which becomes 1 until some process has collected the exit status of the dead ("zombie") process.

Comment: Did you write something special in the child processes? When they check for their "brothers" and respawn themselves when somebody in the family dies, the pid changes. But that would be a special implementation, written by the author of the child process.

Comment: @WalterA no no, but I solved the problem setting a shared memory between parent and children in which I saved each pid. It seems to work. So it was only my impression. Thank you all.